# Can swift optionals be mapped to new values?

Tags: swift

In java 8, you can do the following: -

```
Optional<String> foo = Optional.empty(); // or Optional.of("hello");
foo.map(String::toUpperCase).orElse("Empty String")
```

**edit - another example**

```
class Bar {
  public Bar(final String baz) { ... }
}

foo.map(f -> new Bar(f)) // has mapped into an optional Bar
```

That toUpperCase was a little too simplified; I'm thinking more like being able to specify a lambda or function that can provide a mutated value based on an optional present.

I see that you can do the following in swift: -

```
guard let foo = optional else { return "Empty String" }
```

which is massively useful, and also

```
optional ?? "Empty String"
```

but is there any way to map a value based on the value being optionally present? i.e. so if a value is present, you can return a mutated value?

This functionality is also available for java/c# collections

Comment: Perhaps giving the Java or C# for what you actually mean would be helpful. It's particularly unclear what you mean here by "mutated." I believe you mean mapped.

Comment: Added an example however I wasn't aware of '$0' allowing me to acquire the value which can be passed to wherever I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say for a given array of optional strings, you can make use of optional chaining within your `map` operation

```
let foo: [String?] = ["foo", "bar", nil, "baz"]

let bar = foo.map { $0?.uppercaseString ?? "Empty string" }
print(bar) // ["FOO", "BAR", "Empty string", "BAZ"]
```

A possibly more useful alternative is to apply a `flatMap` operation to simply remove `nil`-valued optional entries from the string array

```
let foo: [String?] = ["foo", "bar", nil, "baz"]

let bar = foo.flatMap { $0?.uppercaseString }
print(bar) // ["FOO", "BAR", "BAZ"]
```

---

W.r.t. your comment, you could e.g. call a failable initializer for, say, some structure `Foo`, within the `flatMap` operation, yielding an array of `Foo` instances given that the initializer succeeds.

```
struct Foo {
    let foo: String
    init?(bar: String?) {
        guard let foo = bar else {
            return nil
        }
        self.foo = foo
    }
}

let foo: [String?] = ["foo", "bar", nil, "baz"]
let bar = foo.flatMap { Foo(bar: $0) }
print(bar) // [Foo(foo: "foo"), Foo(foo: "bar"), Foo(foo: "baz")]
```

Comment: This looks close, but I assume it's limited to using the operator to optionally call the uppercaseString, i.e. I couldn't do something a little more complicated, such as what I commented on Rob's answer with?

Comment: That looks like what I'm after, the $0 is used as a parameter to a function, i.e. something like a higher order function that returns a value. In this case. you're passing the value, if present, an returning a Foo instance.

Comment: @chrisw `$0` is the single parameter of the anonymous (trailing) closure that is used as argument to the `flatMap` operations; in so, `flatMap` is a higher order function that takes a closure as an argument. The values "given" as argument to parameter `$0` are the elements of the array (here: `foo`).

Comment: That's what I'm after, I wasn't aware of the '$0' parameter, which is basically provided to me out of the optional if present :)

Comment: @chrisw Happy to help. For further reading, possibly take a look at the [Language Guide - Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) as well as the part regarding optionals in the [Language Guide -  The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, that's just:

```
optional?.uppercaseString ?? "EMPTY STRING"
```

or if you'd prefer to modify after defaulting:

```
(optional ?? "empty string").uppercaseString
```

Did you have something more complicated in mind?

(You may be unfamiliar with the `?.` operator. It's called optional chaining in Swift, and is similar to `map`.)

Comment: So, maybe my example was a little too simplified, perhaps if I were to mutate a little further, i.e. if I had an optional tuple that I wanted to map into an object. i.e. (30, "Christopher"), could be to a Person struct that takes age and name.

Comment: It's unclear here whether you're trying to map an individual tuple or a collection of them. It's also unclear what you mean by "mutate" in these cases.

Comment: Sorry, how about if I ask, can I specify a lambda or a function to mutate the value to whatever is returned from the lambda, where the parameter passed to it is the optionally present value